# Prove that for any given $r > 0$, there exists a positive constant $c $ such that for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, $\log (2r) \leq cr^\epsilon $

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, logarithms

> Prove that for any given $r > 0$, there exists a positive constant $c $ such that for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, $\log (2r) \leq cr^\epsilon $.

This question comes from a proof of the Hadamard's theorem on entire functions of finite order. This question arises toward the end of Hadamard's theorem shown [here](https://jerrymathematics.wordpress.com/2018/12/22/hadamard-factorization-theorem/). If I have misstated what seems the proof of the hadamard's theorem implies, I would be grateful if you could correct me as well. I am wondering if there is an easy way to find such a constant $c $. I was thinking of using Bernoulli's inequality, but since $\epsilon $ is small I couldn't yet find an obvious way tonsolve this problem.

Comment: Let $r=2/3.$ Then the right hand side tends to $0$ when $\varepsilon \to  \infty..$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln (2r)\leq 2r<cr^{\epsilon}$ if $r^{1-\epsilon} <\frac  c  2$ which is true if $\max \{r^{0},r^{1}\}<\frac c  2$. So we can take any $c >2 \max \{r^{0},r^{1}\}$

Comment: @CuteBrownie I have posted an answer for your new version.